# Update some plots in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to have plots that are updated at different time points?

My model looks like that (it is replicator dynamics):

```
to go
  repeat 10 [do-something]
  replicate
  tick
end
```

Then I would like to have one plot that is updated on `tick`, just like usual, and the second one that is updated at `do-something` and then reset at `tick`.

I tried to find a solution in documentation but `update-plots` command updates ALL plots which is not what i want.

Comment: we used to be able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the various manual plotting commands (eg `plotxy`, `plot-pen-down`, `plot-pen-up`) to explicitly plot things, see the plotting section of the user manual, but is often simpler to have the plot commands in the plot rather than the code.

To do it in the plot instead of code, you could change to a structure like this (if your full code is suitable):

```
to go
  do-something
  if ticks mod 10 = 0 [ replicate ]
  tick
end
```

and use the automatic update of plots with `tick`. You would also use the `if ticks mod 10 = 0` trick in the `update` section of your plot.